# Limit Records fetched in Android (Sqlite database)

Tags: sql, android, sqlite, pagination

I am trying to fetch sms messages from inbox, sent items and drafts. I would like to do a pagination for my list view for that it's imperative that I fetch records in pages/chunks.

I am not familiar with sqlite which is the database I understand android use to store the data. Can someone tell me how can I restrict the number of records I am fetching by using contentResolver.query?

Also what is the way to pull the sqlite database file onto my machine and browse/query it locally to experiment or see data on my machine?

**Are there any other better ways to implement pagination in android??**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any way to limit your results from the [`SmsProvider`](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#yWp0w9CmGlI/src/com/android/providers/telephony/SmsProvider.java&q=SmsProvider.java&sa=N&cd=8&ct=rc). However you shouldn't really need to, given that you use `CursorAdapter` and don't try to read the contents into your own data structures. Have you tried this?

Comment: can you please point me to some examples of as to how CursorAdapter is used?

Comment: This has a good one http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/

Answer (score 8):

According to the [Sqlite website](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#select-stmt), you can use a **`LIMIT ... OFFSET ...`** clause in your query:

Comment: This is what I use too - LIMIT. 
SELECT * from mytable LIMIT 100

Answer (score 5):

For anyone stumbling across this answer looking for a way to use a `LIMIT` clause with an `OFFSET`, I found out from [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5318) that Android uses the following regex to parse the limit clause of a query:

> In framework/base/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:
>
> LIMIT clause is checked with following sLimitPattern.
>
> ```
> private static final Pattern sLimitPattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*\\d+\\s*(,\\s*\\d+\\s*)?");
> ```

Note that the regex does accept the format `offsetNumber,limitNumber` even though it doesn't accept the `OFFSET` statement directly.

Comment: Excellent find! :) This will be helpful I am sure.

Answer (score 1):

To pull your database for viewing, make a copy of it on the SD card and then use adp pull to get it.