# paging in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

How to use paging in android sqlite? any example code directly in java?

I am using

```
Cursor cursor = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_DATE, KEY_REPS, 
KEY_WEIGHT}, null, null, null, null, KEY_DATE + "DESC", ???);
```

Comment: see http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ScrollingCursor

Comment: I want for Android Java code

Comment: So you want to know how to use SQL from Java/Android?

Answer (score 0):

Here there is a similar question/answer [Limit Records fetched in Android (Sqlite database)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691513/limit-records-fetched-in-android-sqlite-database)

Some of the suggestions there are to use LIMIT ... OFFSET in your query, or to create your custom Cursor Adaptor. I guess it depends in which level you want to do the paging.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *LIMIT* keyword with index and no. of rows to fetch certain records, it goes something like this:

```
Cursor cursor = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_DATE,   KEY_REPS, 
KEY_WEIGHT}, null, null, null, null, KEY_DATE + "DESC LIMIT index, No. of records to fetch", ???);
```

Hope this helps.